# How to limit call-rate of Accounts.forgotPassword in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

`Accounts.forgotPassword` is a client methods, and it will trigger the server to send an email, so we need to limit the call-rate.

It has built-in call-rate limit, but I think the limit is too low and I want to change it.

I didn't find any official sollution, only figured out a work-around: wrap the `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail` method. But this is not good because client can still call `Accounts.forgotPassword` to over send emails.

So, I don't know how to handle this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [DDPRateLimiter](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ddpratelimiter) documentation, you could add something like this:

```js
var rule = {type: 'method', method: 'forgotPassword'};
DDPRateLimiter.addRule(rule, 2, 60000);
```

That should limit calls to `forgotPassword` to 2 per minute. You can see other examples [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_rate_limit.js).